# Phantom column name in MS SQL Table, what is it?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am trying to write an MS SQL statement to fetch a row.

```
SELECT otherfields, phantom_col FROM mytable WHERE id=5
```

The above SQL fails with error:

```
Msg 207 Level 16 Stage 1, Line XX
invalid column name 'phantom_col'.
```

I loaded SQL Management Studio 2008 R2 and connected to the said database and table and did a "select top 1000 rows" to get the auto generated SQL. It shows:

```
SELECT TOP 1000 [otherfields], [phantom_col] FROM [mydatabase].[dbo].[mytable]
```

I then deleted the part that reads `[mydatabase]` and immediately SQL Management Studio tells me `[phantom_col]` is invalid.

What special kind of column is that `phantom_col`? Strictly speaking, if I omit the lengthy `[].[]` notation, is my SQL syntax still correct?

EDIT: I looked finally looked closely enough and realised there is an error message. edited as above.

Comment: I think that you're not connected to `mydatabase`, but for example the "Master" database, and the "lengthy" notation explicitly points your query window to that database.

Comment: What happens if you try `select phantom_col from dbo.mytable where id=5` ?

Comment: Sorry, but what is a "Master" database? In the actual SQL, there are like 20+ columns and only 4 "phamtom" columns. For all the other columns, the explicit [].[] reference is not required. please see edit.

Comment: @MarkBannister without the [database] reference, only the "non-phantom" columns can be fetched.

Comment: That didn't answer my question. What happens if you try `select phantom_col from dbo.mytable where id=5` ?

Comment: @MarkBannister error as above.

Comment: @Jake: The "Master" database is a database that's automatically created with every SQL Server installation and contains data the SQL Server needs.

Comment: What about the other fields? If you omit phantom_col and [mydatabase] they should give a similar error. If not that's magic (and scary).

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar ends up you are right, but you aready know it. After much confusion and frustration, I finally realised that there is a similarly named default database with the exact same table and same column names except for the 4 phantom_col. I wasn't connecting to the correct database and my eye's didn't spot the spelling difference!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your syntax is correct.
The error, because you haven't connect to the myDatabse

you can use this too

```
USE mydatabase
GO
SELECT TOP 1000 phantom_col 
FROM myTable
```

> When a SQL Server login connects to SQL Server, the login is
>   automatically connected to its default database and acquires the
>   security context of a database user. If no database user has been
>   created for the SQL Server login, the login connects as guest. If the
>   database user does not have CONNECT permission on the database, the
>   USE statement will fail. If no default database has been assigned to
>   the login, its default database will be set to master.

the quote is taken from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188366.aspx)